# Query CosmosDB when document contains Dictionary

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a problem with querying CosmosDB document which contains a dictionary. This is an example document:

```
{
    "siteAndDevices": {
        "4cf0af44-6233-402a-b33a-e7e35dbbee6a": [
            "f32d80d9-e93a-687e-97f5-676516649420",
            "6a5eb9fa-c961-93a5-38cc-ecd74ada13ac",
            "c90e9986-5aea-b552-e532-cd64a250ad10",
            "7d4bfdca-547a-949b-ccb3-bbf0d6e5d727",
            "fba51bfe-6a5e-7f25-e58a-7b0ced59b5d8",
            "f2caac36-3590-020f-ebb7-5ccd04b4412c",
            "1b446af7-ba74-3564-7237-05024c816a02",
            "7ef3d931-131e-a639-10d4-f4dd5db834ca"
        ]
    },
    "id": "f9ef9fb6-4b70-7d3f-2bc8-c3d335018624"
}
```

I need to get all documents where provided guid is in the list, so in the dictionary value (I don't know dictionary key). I found an information somewhere here that it is not possible to iterate through keys in dictionary in CosmosDB (maybe it has changed since that time but I din't find any information in documentation), but maybe someone will have some idea. I cannot change form of the document.

I tried to do it in Linq, but I didn't get any results.

```
var query = _documentClient
                .CreateDocumentQuery<Dto>(DocumentCollectionUri())
                .Where(d => d.SiteAndDevices.Any(x => x.Value.Contains("f32d80d9-e93a-687e-97f5-676516649420")))
                .AsDocumentQuery();
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure of the Linq query, but with SQL, you'd need something like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM c
where array_contains(c.siteAndDevices['4cf0af44-6233-402a-b33a-e7e35dbbee6a'],"f32d80d9-e93a-687e-97f5-676516649420")
```

This is a strange document format though, as you've named your *key* with an id:

```
"siteAndDevices": {
     "4cf0af44-6233-402a-b33a-e7e35dbbee6a": ["..."]
}
```

Your *key* is `"4cf0af44-6233-402a-b33a-e7e35dbbee6a"`, which forces you to use a different syntax to reference it:

```
c.siteAndDevices['4cf0af44-6233-402a-b33a-e7e35dbbee6a']
```

You'd save yourself a lot of trouble refactoring this to something like:

```
{
   "id": "dictionary1",
   "siteAndDevices": {
      "deviceId": "4cf0af44-6233-402a-b33a-e7e35dbbee6a",
      "deviceValues": ["..."]
   }
}
```

You can refactor further, such as using an array to contain multiple device id + value combos.

Comment: Thanks but I really don't know the key value (this is the thing that I want to retrieve), so it's not possible for me. Yeah I know that the format is weird but I cannot change that, it would force me to go through whole system and I just can't do that.

Comment: @ majewka, me too struck with same situation where I don't know the key value, did find out way to solve it?

Comment: @191180rk - Please note that Stack Overflow isn't set up to be a discussion forum. And if the OP did, indeed, find a different solution, then it would be upon them to post a proper answer to their own question (and not discuss within the comments of another answer). I would suggest that you ask a new question specific to your issue. My answer here stands as-is, explaining exactly how to reference property names with bracket syntax, as well as searching within arrays.

Comment: @DavidMakogon, I can't use bracket syntax because the key is random & object Im referring here is not array rather it is dictionary whose key is random. My actual relate to this concern is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63451606/querying-complex-nested-object-in-cosmosdb-using-sql-api