# Query/Filter CosmosDB Core SQL by key name value

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have the following data structure (to be able to query and filter by day):

```
"id": "someId",
"dailyPlan": {
    "2020-04-07": {
        "activityCategoryOne": {
            "activityOne": "someID",
            "activityTwo": "someIDTwo"
        }
    }
}
```

So now I want to query only the items from the past and the next two weeks. But I have no idea how I can query the key name ("2020-04-07").
Is this possible and if so could you give me a hint or a link to the documentation as I couldn't find anything about it in my research.

Thank you very much!

Best,
Tixamaster

Comment: Use udf to create a custom function or turn your key to be the value like "date":"2020-04-07". I haven't found any doc to achieve your goal too :(

Comment: Keys should be fixed paths, not queryable variables. As commented, best to refactor into a `date` property with the date as value.

Comment: Agreed with the other comments. Storing actual content as a *key* instead of a *value* is an anti-pattern. Once you move your date to be a value of some property, then you'll have the entirety of the SQL API's query capabilities at your fingertips. There's really no solution other than brute-force, when designing a schema like this. I answered another question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62224692/272109), where part of the issue was exactly this as well (and you can look at the refactoring I included in my answer, where you could take a similar approach).

Answer (score 0):

As comments said, it's impossible to achieve this by SQL in Cosmos DB.

The best workaround is to change your schema like this:

```
"id": "someId",
"dailyPlan": {
    "date": "2020-04-07",
    "activityCategoryOne": {
        "activityOne": "someID",
         "activityTwo": "someIDTwo" 
    }
}
```

Then use SQL like this:

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.dailyPlan.date BETWEEN xxx AND xxx
```