# Unable to queries in nested object in CosmosDB entry

Tags: sql, azure-cosmosdb

Is there a way to query a nested object within a document in CosmosDB when there are multiple nested items with same id:

```
{
  id: "GUID", 
    "items"[ 
     {   
         "item": {
            "item_id": "123456",
            "order_name": "name1"
          },
         "item": {
             "item_id": "123456",
             "order_name": "name2",
          }
    }]
}
```

Id be looking to check the `item_id` and pull back that `item` object. Using the query `SELECT c.item FROM c WHERE c.item.item_id = '123456'`  will only work if there is only one item but with more than one the query does not return anything. Using the query `SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.item.item_id = '123456'` doesn't bring back anything either.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your data model, as what you've shown doesn't really work. You have two `"item"` subdocuments, each with the exact same key name of `"item"`. Can you please clarify? Note: If putting data in a key creates a difficult query scenario for you, and I would argue it's an anti-pattern. FYI take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62224692/272109) I posted a while back, talking about exactly this.

Comment: The key in JSON should be unique: [RFC-4627](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt?number=4627), so how will you access different `item`s?

Comment: So, with the edit: you still have the same fundamental data-modeling issue: You've used a literal string (a bit of data) as your key. This isn't really something you should do. You don't even need that key - you can just include your subdocuments. Or, if you'll have multiple subdocuments per array item, you can have a property for the key, like `item` - not a string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question but here a couple of ways to work with nested queries:

**Option 1:**

```
SELECT
    c.id,
    items
FROM c
JOIN (SELECT 
        b.item_id,
        b.order_name
    FROM b WHERE b.parentID = c.id) AS items
```

The query will return the "items" field as an object

**Option 2:**

```
SELECT
    c.id,
    ARRAY (
        SELECT 
            b.item_id,
            b.order_name
        FROM b WHERE b.parentID = c.id)
    ) AS items
FROM c
```

The query will return the "items" field as an array of objects

Comment: This isn't an issue with nested queries; it's an issue with the actual schema. Also, querying data in a nested array is achieved via `ARRAY_CONTAINS()`, which is shown in the answer I linked to in my comment.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Thanks for clarifying the issue. Related to "ARRAY_CONTAINS" is to indicate whether the array contains the specified value, Correct? The "ARRAY" keyword is used to construct an array from the subquery's results [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-object-array).