# Dynamic Properties in Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I went through many post on SO. Not finding what I need.

I am having a collection document which is like below

```
    [
        {
           "Key1": "Value",
           "Key2": 1,
           "Key3": "Value",
           "Key4": 5,
           "Date": "2021-10-25T04:20:00",
           "Key5": {
              "a3": "2021-09-03T09:32:55",
              "a199": "2021-09-03T09:32:55"
           }
        },
        {
           "Key1": "Value",
           "Key2": 1,
           "Key3": "Value",
           "Key4": 5,
           "Date": "2021-10-25T04:20:00",
           "Key5": {
              "a500": "2021-09-03T09:32:55",
              "a39": "2021-09-03T09:32:55"
           }
        }
     ]
```

I am using this query

```
Select top 10 * from Collection c where c.Key5.a3 = '2021-09-03T09:32:55'
```

Now I need to filter the data from this collection where Key5.a3 or Key5.a199 is equals to something. The problem here is I don't know Which properties will be coming under Key5, Those are created by system randomly from UI and each document will have different properties in Key5.

I need to build a query for this collection which will not care about the Key5.a199/399/500 or anything but just compare the value associated with it.

Comment: I don't quite understand the use of `Key1` through `Key4` - seems like you're pairing properties somehow? That said: You cannot have variable property names. You've created your need for this because you've used actual data as your property names. Try changing, say, `Key5` to have an array of subdocuments with `key` and `value` properties, with `key` being `a500` and `value` being the date, etc. Then you always query on the same names. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62224692/272109) I posted a while back, showing something similar, to a similar question.

Comment: @DavidMakogon You are correct Devid. Now We are half way there in the implementation. I dont think that we will be able to change the structure of the document as it will be lots of changes. Please ignore Key1 to Key4. On Key5 we are having this one service which create one entry in other document and add reference here. That Key is autogenerated and will be changing for each entry. I hope I clarify your doubt.

Comment: Where are you executing the query from ? Is it from the portal or through some coded application. And if Yes then what language? Not possible through 1 sql query but may be possible through code.

Comment: @AnupamChand - this would require doing a full parse of every document to find needed data, as there is real data stored as property names. This is non-trivial, and likely expensive. And storing actual data as a property name is an anti-pattern (since there's just no straightforward way to query such data). Querying from the portal vs code doesn't really matter; the problem exists regardless where such queries are performed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have dynamic queries that ignore a particular property's name.

The problem you have is created by storing data values as property names (both with `Key1` through `Key4` and your more complex `Key5`. Specifically:

```json
"Key5": {
   "a500": "2021-09-03T09:32:55",
   "a39": "2021-09-03T09:32:55"
}
```

You've embedded metadata into your property names, which is the issue when attempting to index or search.

To avoid this, refactor your data model to have consistent property names. Something like this, where you have well-defined key-value pairs. You can then have multiple values, within an array. Something like this:

```json
{
   "Key5": [
      { "property_key": "a500", "property_value": "2021-09-03T09:32:55" },
      { "property_key": "a39", "property_value" : "2021-09-03T09:32:55" }
   ]
}
```

At this point, you'd now have a consistent set of property names to query.

You'd need to custom-tailor this to your needs, but this shows how to avoid the problem of storing real data in property names.

Comment: I also have a legacy system with dynamic json keys. Any idea how I can just check the existence of the keys inside the json. I want to do `select from where ('a500', 'a39') in key5` => obviously I don't know the syntax for that. It's similar to JSON_KEYS in mysql.